# How to use UNION ALL when there is IN clause?

Tags: mysql, union-all

I have a query like this:

```
select p.title
from Posts p
where p.id in (select id from Votes where timestamp between $x and $y);
```

Now want to use this table instead of `Posts`:

```
select title from Posts1
union all
select title from Posts2
```

How can I write this ^ instead of `Posts` in the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest the query

```
select title from
(select id,title from Posts1 union all select id,title from Posts2) from t1
where t1.id in (select id from Votes where timestamp between $x and $y);
```

or add the where query to both select queries:

```
select title from Posts1 where Posts1.id in (select id from Votes where timestamp between $x and $y)
union all
select title from Posts2 where Posts2.id in (select id from Votes where timestamp between $x and $y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below query, hope it will perform better-

```
SELECT p.title FROM Posts1 p JOIN votes v ON p.id=v.id
WHERE v.timestamp BETWEEN $X AND $Y
UNION ALL 
SELECT p.title FROM Posts2 p JOIN votes v ON p.id=v.id
WHERE v.timestamp BETWEEN $X AND $Y;
```

Comment: In principle: SQL is declarative so the db should optimise it ;)

Comment: SQL is always declarative ;)

Comment: `INDEX(timestamp, id)` on `Votes` would be useful.

Comment: Can't you get duplicate ids?  If so, consider `UNION DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select title from (select id,title from Posts1 union all select id,title from Posts2) p
where p.id in (select id from Votes where timestamp between $x and $y);
```

or you can do it like

```
select title from Posts1 p1 where p1.id in (select id from Votes where timestamp between $x and $y)
union all
select title from Posts2 p2 where p2.id in (select id from Votes where timestamp between $x and $y);
```

Comment: I think you have to remove the last `from` in your first query at line 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join in your query. That will solve the issue

```
select Posts.title from Posts inner join Votes on Posts.id=Votes.id
where votes.timestamp between $x and $y
```